# How can I have permanent redirects and rewrite rules on the same site

Tags: angularjs, redirect, web-config, url-rewriting

In my web.config I have this rule set up for AngularJS (HTML5Mode)

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/token" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then I have a load of 301 redirects set up like this:

```
<location path="about.html">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/about" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

obviously the redirects are not being reached. How can I get my rewriter to only apply to anything that is not being redirected?

I hope that makes sense.

### Update

I removed the rewrite rule just to test if the redirects work without it. They do, but my application is still working.
I was sure I needed the rewrite rule for HTML5mode. Is that not the case?

### Update 2

It seems the rewriter is for url parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I didn't know is that you can add redirects to the rewrite rules. If you add them first and set the **stopProcessing** flag to true, it will redirect and not "hit" the rewrite rule.

Here is an example:

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="301" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="volleyball" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/token" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```